# Miss understanding related with the energy density of radiation in the context of cosmology

Tags: cosmology, definition

The usual definition of radiation energy density in the context of statistical physics is given by
$$U=a_{B}T^{4}$$

With $a_{B}=7.5657\times 10^{-16} J m^{-3} K^{-4}$. So $U$ has units of $J m^{-3}$

On the other hand I read in some  General relativity textbooks that  the parameter $\rho$ (the parameter that appears in the Friedmann equations) is the  energy density, but if I look at  the units in the of the Friedmann equation for the Hubble parameter

$$H^{2}=\frac{8 \pi G }{3}\rho$$

I find that $\rho$ has units of $kg/m^3$. So in the particular case of radiation $\rho_{r}$ don't have the same units as $U$,  then $\rho_{r}$ is not the  energy density of radiation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In astrophysics and cosmology it is common to omit factors of $c$, where $c$ is the speed of light. This means that in these units an energy density will look like a mass density. To fix this, you have to put in a factor $c^2$.

Comment: I know that the correct relation is $U=c^{2}\rho_{r}$, but I was looking for some reference.

However your answer makes more clear my problem, thank you.